# ASP.Net Synchronization with Quickbooks Onine using Intuit Services

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have a quick books sandbox account and a trial database, i want to connect my asp.net  application with its database using web services. 
Requirement is whenever we insert anything into our database, it should also be inserted into Quickbooks database.
I have studied Intuit SDK and as per their flow, we have to authorize our request using oAuth process, whenever we need to do any action.

My requirement is very simple, i have a service createItem() in my application deployed on an online server, if this services is called, it should also create that item on quickbooks online database. I want this process to be generic, services will work automatically as per actions. Is there any way?  I just want that there should be no oAuth/Redirection.

Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how OAuth works.

The OAuth redirections only occurs *once*. Once you have gone through the OAuth flow *once*, you **never** have to go through it again. Ever.

The purpose of the OAuth redirection is to securely supply your website with a set of tokens that it can use to connect in the future. So once you have those tokens, you *never* have to redirect someone ever again, and the process can be fully automated beyond that.

What you're trying to do is perfectly possible.

Comment: Yes i have used concept of IPP, the only problem it is giving; 400- Bad Request. If i use any tool to send http request on same url with similar header and body, they give output but with asp.net DevAuth library it is giving this error even i have copied the solution from somewhere.

Comment: So post your code, or something else that might be even remotely useful for us to help you troubleshoot.